# Lock Element Position Relative to Another Element

Tags: jquery, css

When my page loads, I find the position of `div_left` on the page and set the top of `div_right` so that they appear side by side. This is the only way I have found to do this because my page is complicated with multiple forms and such. The code to find/set position is this:

```
function findPos() {
    var curLeft = curTop = 0;
    var obj = $("#div_left");
    var position = obj.position();
    curLeft = position.left;
    curTop = position.top;
    moveToPos(curLeft, curTop);
}

function moveToPos(newLeft, newTop) {
    $("#div_right").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: newTop + "px",
        left: (newLeft + 550) + "px"
    });
}
```

The elements that appear above these divs change size regularly, primarily via `.toggle()`. I'm finding that `div_right` doesn't move with the rest of the page elements when the elements above it are "expanding" or "contracting". Is there a way to "append" `div_right` to something or make it a child of something so that I don't have to programmatically move it every time? This would be painful due to the `.toggle()` animating.

**EDIT 1**

[image]

So you can see, I can't contain `div_left` and `div_right` in a larger div because I'd be cutting through `form1`. As far as I know, a form cannot be split up.

**EDIT 2**

Basic HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
<table id="table1"></table>
<div id="div_left"></div>
</form>

<div id="div_right">
<form id="form2"></form>
</div>
```

Comment: are they required to be side by side all of the time? if so then you can put them in the same "row" or same div container. Can you post some markup of the html so we understand the situation a little bit more? if you can a simplified http://www.jsfiddle.net would help even more

Comment: Yes I want them to remain side by side. I added a simple image of the layout. Putting div_left and div_right inside a div container would split form1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try and explain how your code is different from this working fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/FFnyA/2

Edit: posting code for posterity

## html

```
<form method='post' id='form1'>
    <div id='table_container'>
        <table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></table>
    </div>
    <div id='div_left'>
    </div>
</form>
<div id='div_right'>
    <form method='post' id='form2'>
    </form>
</div>
<div style='clear:both'></div>
<div id='other_content'>
    <p>Look at me</p>
</div>​
```

## css

```
#table_container
{
    background-color: pink;
}
#div_left
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lime;
}
#div_right
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: cyan;
}
​
```

Fiddle with code from [Huangism](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1058134/huangism) 's suggestion http://jsfiddle.net/FFnyA/6/

Comment: I've been playing with that fiddle. It's a simple solution that I haven't tried. I'm going to try and implement it. To answer your question, I have some forms intertwined with the divs, but I added them to the fiddle and it still works.

Comment: it is invalid html to put divs inside of form tag

Comment: So this code works fine as long as the window is large enough. I find that if I shrink the window past a certain threshold (but div_right is still completely visible), div_right jumps to below div_left. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Kevin_TA If you shrink the window enough, yes, that will happen. `#div_right` will jump just before it would add a scroll bar. The problem here is the form wrapper... I'll try to think of something.

Comment: you can add an overall wrapper make it relative position, and div _right can be absolute and position it to bottom:0 and right:0 so it is always at the bottom corner, this would assuming your div_left and right are the same height and fixed width. In http://jsfiddle.net/FFnyA/5/ I used left: 100px instead, you can use right:0 deending on your width of the top table

Comment: @Huangism, if I understood you correctly, that allows the div_right to overlap div_left when the window is resized.

Comment: @Kevin_TA no it would not overlap, try it on the fiddle, the overall wrapper's width does not change so when you resize the window it would not overlap. If you use the left:100px method then it would not overlap no matter what

Answer (score 0):

Well I am sure the code is more complicated than that picture but you can try putting div_right inside of div_left and div_left would be positioned relatively, div_right will be positioned absolutely. Put CSS "left" for div_right to the width + margin-right of div_left and top:0; you should have what you have in the picture.

This is assuming div_left is fixed width

Update: something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/FFnyA/5/

Comment: Doing what you proposed, wouldn't that cause form2 to be nested inside form1?

Comment: @Kevin_TA no, you add form 2 when form 1 ends and sicne div_right will be positioned absolutely, there is no visual mix up either